# Find minimum value $m$ such that $2(x + \sqrt{4 - x^2}) = m + x\sqrt{4 - x^2}$ has at least three distinct real roots.

Tags: polynomials

> Calculate the minimum value of $m$ such that the equation $$\large 2(x + \sqrt{4 - x^2}) = m + x\sqrt{4 - x^2}$$ has at least three distinct real roots.

$(x \in [-2, 2])$

We have that $$2(x + \sqrt{4 - x^2}) = m + x\sqrt{4 - x^2} \iff (x - 2)(\sqrt{4 - x^2} - 2) = 4 - m$$

$(\implies m \in (-\infty, 4])$

Let $\sqrt{4 - x^2} = y \ (\implies x^2 + y^2 = 4)$, we have that $(x - 2)(y - 2) = x^2 + y^2 - m$

$$ \iff x^2 + y^2 - (x - 2)(y - 2) = m \iff y^2 - (x - 2)y + (x^2 + 2x - 4 - m) = 0$$

I could only assume that for the equation $$2(x + \sqrt{4 - x^2}) = m + x\sqrt{4 - x^2}$$ to have at least three distinct real roots, the equation $$y^2 - (x - 2)y + (x^2 + 2x - 4 - m) = 0$$ must have two distinct real roots, which means $$ \Delta = (x - 2)^2 - 4(x^2 + 2x - 4 - m) = 4m - 3x^2 - 12x + 20 > 0$$

Additionally, $x \in [-2, 2] \implies 3x^2 + 12x - 20 \in [-32, 16] \iff m \in [-8, 4]$, in which case, the solutions are $$y = \frac{1}{2}(\pm\sqrt{4m - 3x^2 - 12x + 20} + x - 2)$$

Then I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For real $x,$ we need $4-x^2\ge0\iff-2\le x\le2$

WLOG $x=2\sin t$

$$4(\sin t+\cos t)=m+4\sin t\cos t$$

Now if $\sin t+\cos t=u, u^2=1+2\sin t\cos t, u^2\le2$

$$4u=m+2(u^2-1)$$  which is on arrangement is a quadratic equation in $u$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note 
$$m(x) = \large 2(x + \sqrt{4 - x^2}) - x\sqrt{4 - x^2}\tag 1$$

Set $m'(x) = 0$ to get

$$x^2+\sqrt{4-x^2}-x-2=0$$
and factorize,

$$\sqrt{2+x}=(x+1)\sqrt{2-x}\implies x(x^2-2)=0$$

which leads to the extrema at $x=0$ and $x=\sqrt2$. As seen from the graph, for $m(\sqrt2) < m < m(0)$, the equation (1) has three roots. Thus,

$$m(\sqrt2)= 4\sqrt2-2$$

is the lower bound for $m$.

Answer (score 0):

The hint.

Let $x+\sqrt{4-x^2}=t.$

Thus, by C-S $$t^2\leq2(x^2+4-x^2)=8,$$ which gives $$-2\leq t\leq2\sqrt2$$ and $$x\sqrt{4-x^2}=\frac{t^2-4}{2}.$$
Id est, $$2t-\frac{t^2-4}{2}=m$$ or
$$4-\frac{(t-2)^2}{2}=m,$$
which gives $m\leq4.$

For $m=4$ we obtain $t=2,$ which gives only two roots of the equation.

Id est, $$m<4.$$
Now, use that $t=k$ has unique root for $-2\leq k<2$ and has two distinct roots for $2\leq k<2\sqrt2.$

Answer (score 0):

For there to be three or more real roots, then for three or more values of $x$, we must get the same $m$

$$\large 2(x + \sqrt{4 - x^2}) = m + x\sqrt{4 - x^2}$$

Rewriting

$$\large  m  = 2(x + \sqrt{4 - x^2}) - x\sqrt{4 - x^2} $$

So I graphed this...  [image: graph of m vs x]

So, the maximum value for m would be 2.

It appears the minimum is at $x=\sqrt{2}$
where 
\begin{align}
m & = 2(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{2}^2} - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{4-\sqrt{2}^2} \\
 & = 2(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2})-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2} \\
 & = 4\sqrt{2} - 2 \\
 & \approx 3.65685424949238019520 \\
\end{align}

so
$m \in ( 4\sqrt{2}-2, 4 )$

Edit: I missed that the request was for *distinct* roots, so the interval is open on both ends.